# How to get days between date range by using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a form, I define a start date, an end date, and weekdays

Example:

```
Start date: 2017-02-07
End date: 2017-03-07
```

Weekdays: Monday and Thursday

Now I want to get all Mondays and Thursdays between start date and end date by using Javascript or jQuery.

Who can help me?

Thanks...

Comment: @closevoters there is nothing saying that users asking how-to questions are required to include what they've tried so far. This question is not a debugging-style question, is not too broad, and is otherwise clear and on-topic. Please see: [Only debugging style questions explicitly require code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple code. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/shahabaz/pen/QdBzMo?editors=1111)

```
var startDate = new Date('2017-02-07');
var endDate = new Date('2017-02-17');
var monday = [];
var thursday = [];
for (var d = new Date(startDate); d <= new Date(endDate); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    if(d.getDay()==1)
      monday.push(d);
    else if(d.getDay()==4)
      thursday.push(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse date and iterate over increment 1 day and getDay to map with sun(0) to sat(6)

```js
var startDate = new Date("2017-02-07");
var endDate = new Date("2017-03-07");
var totalMon = [];
var totalThu = [];

for (var i = startDate; i <= endDate; ){
    if (i.getDay() == 1){
        totalMon.push(i.getFullYear() + "-" + (i.getMonth()+1) + "-" + i.getDate());
    }
    if (i.getDay() == 4){
       totalThu.push(i.getFullYear() + "-" + (i.getMonth()+1) + "-" + i.getDate());
    }
    i.setTime(i.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24);
}

console.log(totalMon.length ,totalMon);
console.log(totalThu.length ,totalThu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code finds number of Mondays. You can modify it to calculate any day. It basically finds the difference of days in two dates. Divide it by 7 (this is the number of times everyday will come). Now for pending days loop through the dates and check if a desired day comes in this loop.

```
var startDate = new Date(2017, 02, 07);
var endDate = new Date(2017, 03, 07);
var dayDiff = Math.round((endDate-startDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
var numberOfMondays = Math.floor(dayDiff/7);
var remainingDays = dayDiff%7;
for(i=0;i<remainingDays;i++)
{
    var dateObj = new Date();
    dateObj.setDate(endDate.getDate() - i);
    if(dateObj.getDay() == 2)
    numberOfMondays=numberOfMondays+1;
}
alert(numberOfMondays);
```

PS : the other two answer are looping through all the dates. I will not suggest this. In code above the number of iterations in loop will never exceed 6 irrespective of the difference in dates.